# Split a column of a dataframe into two separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, split, strsplit

I'd like to split a column of a dataframe into two separate columns. Here is how my dataframe looks like (only the first 3 rows):

[image]

I'd like to split the column `referenced_tweets` into two columns: `type` and `id` in a way that for example, for the first row, the value of the `type` column would be `replied_to` and the value of `id` would be `1253050942716551168`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
df[['type', 'id']] = df['referenced_tweets'].str.split(',', n=1, expand=True)
```

but I get the error:

> ValueError: Columns must be the same length as key

(I think I get this error because the type in the referenced_tweets column is NOT always `replied_to` (e.g., it can be `retweeted`, and therefore, the lengths would be different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not get the values from the dict and add it two new columns?

```
def unpack_column(df_series, key):
    """ Function that unpacks the key value of your column and skips NaN values """
    return [None if pd.isna(value) else value[0][key] for value in df_series]
    
    
df['type'] = unpack_column(df['referenced_tweets'], 'type')
df['id'] = unpack_column(df['referenced_tweets'], 'id')
```

or in a one-liner:

```
df[['type', 'id']] = df['referenced_tweets'].apply(lambda x: (x[0]['type'], x[0]['id']))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code, but I get this error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Seems that you have some NaN values (missing data) in your column. You need to clean that first

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I can't remove those NaN values (I need the values of other columns where the `referenced_tweets` is NaN)

Comment: Of which column? And what does it contain? These kind of dict lists as well?

Comment: @mOna my edit does take NaN into account and skips over it